# When calling super() in custom view, make sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Here is my code which produces

> Warning: LoaderView(...): When calling super() in `LoaderView`, make
>   sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was
>   passed.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {ActivityIndicator, Text, View} from 'react-native'

    export class LoaderView extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        }

        props = {
            title: "",
            loading: false
        }


        render() {
            if (this.props.loading) {
                return <View {...this.props} style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator
                        size={"large"}
                        animating={true}/>

                    <Text
                        style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '500'}}>
                        {this.props.title}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            } else {
                return <View {...this.props} style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Text
                        style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '500'}}>
                        {this.props.title}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            }
        }

    }
```

How to resolve this warning in above code?

Comment: try 
static defaultProps = {
    title: "",
    loading: false
  };
instead of props = { ... }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use defaultProps instead of props

```
static defaultProps = {
    title: "",
    loading: false
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why defaultProps will work, not props?

Comment: @RahulRastogi if the props passed to constructor is different from the props defined in class, it's implicit which one is "this.props".

Comment: It didn't works for me. I should do instead:
`constructor(props) {  super(props); [...] }`

Answer (score 0):

I got this warning, and it turned out to be a red herring for me. Note that the code works, despite this warning.
The solution is to declare an interface for your props object, and make sure that you not miss any properties. In particular, you might be missing **id**. In my case, a constructor was not needed, and `super(props)` did not help. Example:

```
export interface LoaderProps extends React.Props<LoaderProps> {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  loading: bool;
}

export class LoaderView extends React.Component<LoaderProps> {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used `this.props = props`, this do the trick for me!

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props = props
}
```